# Adding a logfile to probe monitoring list in tomcat 9

Tags: java, logging, tomcat9, probe

I have a project that uses log4j2 to create log files. Log files are created in the log directory in tomcat. I deployed the project on tomcat 9. I want to add the log files to probe9 interface (http://localhost:8080/probe9/logs/list.htm).

I looked for a way to do it from the interface but didn't find any. CUrrently i'm looking to add the log4j2.xml to the tomcat9 lib. Is there a way to do so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through tomcat files, i found the stdout.properties file that contains the names of log files that can be monitored by probe9. The file is in "apache-tomcat-9.0.68/webapps/probe9/WEB-INF/classes/stdout.properties".
just added the name of my log file. WOrked like a charm!